# Can we use MonkeyTalk IDE directly with APK files without project source?

Tags: android, aspectj, monkeytalk

I have used android sample projects and successfully convert them to aspectj project and run the app in emulator and record application action with Monkey Talk IDE.

**now i want to record only .apk file which is not converted to **aspectj*** but failed to record.*

I been looking on AspectJ-Wikipeda and this.

Answer (score 0):

Without source code it was not possible . MonkeyTalk must be compiled into the application under test for it to work. 

But with latest MonkeyTalk IDE pro edition , instrumentation does it automatically. No need of application source code.

Limitation : As of now possible with only android apk.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to use [MonkeyTalk Professional Edition](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk). This is not free source, but however available for trial I guess. You can just provide .apk, it will give you instrumented_with_monkeytalk.apk. You can install this apk for monkeytalk to detect.

Answer (score 0):

I tired to instrument the `.apk` directly from the `MonkeyTalkPro IDE`. I shows instrumenting later it stops saying that `Instrumentation unsuccessful: Error instrumenting the apk` I queried a lot and found that it can't handle the complex application, complex in the sense which has 9-patch images. But I tired for the simple applications still the result is same. Anyone got the success in conversion of apk directly into the instrumented apk.(without any sourcecode and `aspectJ` conversion, just using `monkeytalk IDE`)

Comment: @NiMa regarding your suggested edit, you _do not_ need to turn every quote or project name (like "aspectJ") into `inline code`.  Please use inline code for things that are _actually code_, only.

Comment: I think MonkeyTalk can directly convert the simple Apps, if you have complex structured and using 9-patch images it is not possible. If anyone got the success kindly help me